# Error Deleting Data Row in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

i have a datagridview in C# showing results from query database. I want to delete the data and this method is using DataSet. This method execute when a button pressed in some index.

The code:

```
DialogResult _result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to remove the data?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
if (_result == DialogResult.OK) 
{
    int idx = dataGridInfo.CurrentRow.Index;
    this.getInfoFilmDS.sp_getInfo.Rows.RemoveAt(idx);
    MessageBox.Show("Data Removed", "Processing", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

this method

```
this.getInfoFilmDS.sp_getInfo.Rows.RemoveAt(idx);
```

is working only in the DataGridView but the data itself is not deleted in database.

*How to resolve this?*

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE i've change the syntax into this:

```
this.getInfoFilmDS.sp_getInfo.Rows[idx].Delete();
sp_getInfoTableAdapter.Adapter.Update(getInfoFilmDS);
```

but the compiler throws an error.

```
Invalid Operation Exception Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows.
```

Comment: Did you implement some method to delete on database using ado.net?

Comment: where are you processing your mySql command to delete row from database??? you are not doing anything with back end(MySql) to delete row..

Comment: @felipe this is automatic generated xsd file based on stored procedure in database.

Comment: are you binding some key also from database like Pimary Key to reference a particular row ?

Comment: @sajanyamaha no, the stored procedure itself is JOIN table, and the primary key is autoincrements

Answer (score 0):

[`DataRowCollection.RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.remove.aspx) does only remove the row from the `DataTable`, it does not delete the row (even if you would use a `DataAdapter`). Therefore you need to use [`DataRow.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete.aspx):

```
getInfoFilmDS.sp_getInfo.Rows[idx].Delete();
```

Note that you now need to use a [`DataAdapter`](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDataAdapter.html) to commit the changes in the `DataSet` to the database.

**Update**

> i've change the syntax into this:

```
this.getInfoFilmDS.sp_getInfo.Rows[idx].Delete();
sp_getInfoTableAdapter.Adapter.Update(getInfoFilmDS);
```

but the compiler throws an error:

> Invalid Operation Exception. Update requires a valid DeleteCommand
>   when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows.

So you need to define the `DeleteCommand` which is normally auto generated from the `DataSet` when you select only one table, maybe you just have to reconfigure the `TableAdapter` and it will autocreate the delete-command. Otherwise you have to create it manually:

[**TableAdapter Overview**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: then because it is from automatic xsd, i couldn't find my DataAdapter. How to solve that?

Comment: There is an autogenerated namespace "xzyTableAdapters". There you have to look for the right tableadapter for this table. Create an instance and use it to update the dataset or datatable or datarow. It will commit all changes to the database(all rows with `RowState` is != unchanged).

Comment: okay i've change the syntax into this:

    this.getInfoFilmDS.sp_getInfo.Rows[idx].Delete();         sp_getInfoTableAdapter.Adapter.Update(getInfoFilmDS);

Comment: @randytan: "The compiler throws an error" you have forgotten to tell us the error. Have you created an instance of the tableadapter as i've told you? `TableAdapter.Update` is not static.

Comment: Invalid Operation Exception. Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows. @Tim

Comment: the problem is, the select statement is taken from stored procedure, maybe it's the cause dataset is not autogenerate the DELETE command. Is there any possibility to create the DELETE statement? or i need to create a query ? thanks

Comment: @randytan: It's  easy to create a delete statement in the TableAdapter manuallay, just follow the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

okay after research and asking @Tim for the support, it shows that DataSet is not generating Query based on Stored Procedure (please inform me, if i were wrong :D) so, i need to generate another stored procedure based on JOIN tables..

There are three tables in my MySQL db and i create another stored procedure to delete the data. then i assign the DELETE stored procedure into dataset configuration

then applied this code

```
try
            {
                int idx = dataGridInfo.CurrentRow.Index;
                this.getInfoFilmDS.sp_getInfo.Rows[idx].Delete();
                sp_getInfoTableAdapter.Adapter.Update(getInfoFilmDS);
                MessageBox.Show("Data removed", "Process", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Delete Data" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

it works like a charm.